# How to improve the IIS certificate authentication performance for asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I tried my new API project with .netCore 3.1, where Client Certiticate Authentication is needed.
According to official recommendations, the validation/trust check is done in IIS, and the authorization is done in my code
OnCertificateValidated = context => {...}

I did exactly what "[Configure certificate authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1)" says, however the performance is a disaster.

The process of IIS cert. validation takes 10 to 15 secs. And the IIS does it every 1 or two minutes.
I see there is an option in the .net 5 previews called **AddCertificateCache**().
**Does anymore know if this cache option is helpful? or it only affects cert. validation throug Kestrel or also IIS?**

Comment: Certificate verification is a very complex process (hints from posts like [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/client-certificate-revisited-how-to-troubleshoot-client/ba-p/348053)), so you have to dig further to see what kind of client certificates are there and whether it requires CRL access or any other external access which might be blocked somehow which often is the cause of such delay. You might open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com as Microsoft support team can guide you further.

Comment: Thank you Lex for the help, but your hint isn't helping. There is no error, just slow.

Comment: You can try to clear the SSL state in a browser. Web browsers cache SSL certificates to speed up the browsing experience. when you are developing pages for your web site or installing a new certificate, the browser's SSL state can get in the way.